# Sharepoint Enterprise wiki page layout for mobile devices view

Tags: css, page-layout, custom-masterpage, html, aspx

I am working on SharePoint 2013 Enterprise wiki site, and users are complaining that accessing the wiki pages from their mobile devices is not very user friendly. now i have enabled a site feature named "Mobile Browser View" but noting really changed.

As i know that each enterprise wiki site comes with the following page layout `EnterpriseWiki.aspx` , but i can not find any page layout for mobile devices, or even the current `Enterprisewiki.apsx` does not provide any responsive design features so that the wiki page will adapt its layout based on the screen size.. ?  so can anyone adivce how i can improve the wiki pages appearance on mobile devices ?

Answer (score 0):

The mobile view is using the same page layouts. You can check how your page looks on a mobile device by adding ?mobile=1 behind the page url.